# composer/composer 1.10.8 requires composer/semver ^1.0 -> no matching package found

Tags: magento2, composer

i am trying to do `composer update` on my magento2 installation, which is at version `2.3.4`

i am getting following error

```
  [Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]                                                                                 
  Problem 1                                                                                                                             
      - Installation request for composer/composer @alpha -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.10.8].                                  
      - composer/composer 1.10.8 requires composer/semver ^1.0 -> no matching package found.                                            
    Problem 2                                                                                                                           
      - composer/composer 1.10.8 requires composer/semver ^1.0 -> no matching package found.                                            
      - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4 requires composer/composer ^1.6 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.10.8].            
      - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.4].  
                                                                                                                                        
  Potential causes:                                                                                                                     
   - A typo in the package name                                                                                                         
   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting                                
     see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.                                                 
   - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it                                                        
                                                                                                                                        
  Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

did anybode have similar problem ?

thanks